# MySQL: How to select and find ids in bracket [id] list

Tags: mysql

I have a large database, how can I find identifiers in this example of a database column?

Find in text column [bracket ids]?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `explanations` WHERE `id_Verse` REGEXP in '[1007],[991]'
```

This is a sample query, please suggest a valid query for this sample, select WHERE text.

[image: how can I find identifiers in this example of a database column]

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. Do you want to use a query to look for 1 specific "id_Verse"?

Comment: If you need to search for partials in data like this, I would argue that you rather should restructure your database. Read about [database normalization](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/database-normalization-in-mysql/), specially if you have a large database. Searching for partial results like this in a large data set would be very ineffective and slow since the database won't be able to use indexing or any type of intelligent sorting when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to simplify the expression:

```
\\[(991|1007)\\]
```

As opposed to defining each set of brackets, the above expression finds the set of digits surrounded in brackets `[]` that equals `991` or `1007`.
The `()` parentheses is used to group explicit digit sets while `|` works as an `or` operator between each set.
The backslash \ is used to escape the brackets so they are considered as literal instead of as a regular expression character set match eg: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to match alpha-numeric or `[bfs]ad` to match `bad`, `fad`, or `sad`.
In MySQL queries you need to use two backslashes \ for it to be represented as a literal backslash, as backslash is often used as the [escape sequence character](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences) for example `'Your\'s'`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `explanations`
WHERE `id_Verse` REGEXP '\\[(991|1007)\\]';
```

See working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e541bc1186fe03dc2db377b231989a18) example.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_Verse` TEXT
);

INSERT INTO foo(id_Verse)
VALUES 
   ('[991]'), /* <--- */
   ('[1070]'),
   ('[991][992][1004][1007]'), /* <--- */
   ('[991][992][1004][1007][1010]'), /* <--- */
   ('[1007][1008]'), /* <--- */
   ('[989][991]'), /* <--- */
   ('[9910]'),
   ('[964]'),
   ('[1007]'); /* <--- */
```

| id_Verse |
| --- |
| [991] |
| [991][992][1004][1007] |
| [991][992][1004][1007][1010] |
| [1007][1008] |
| [989][991] |
| [1007] |

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities besides LIKE

But a simpler solution would be normalize your table and use bridge table to store the ids

> ```
> CREATE TABLe explanations (id_Verse vARCHAR(100),
>        FULLTEXT idx (id_Verse))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO explanations VALUES ('[1007][991]'),('[991][1008]'),('[1006][1007][1008]'),('[1010]')
> ```

## using [rEGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)

> ```
>     SELECT * FROM `explanations` WHERE `id_Verse` REGEXP '(\\[991\\]|\\[1007\\])'
> ```

> ```
> | id_Verse           |
> | :----------------- |
> | [1007][991]        |
> | [991][1008]        |
> | [1006][1007][1008] |
> ```

## using [FULL TEXT SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `explanations` WHERE MATCH(id_Verse) AGAINST('[1007]' '[991]')
> ```
>
> ```
> | id_Verse           |
> | :----------------- |
> | [1007][991]        |
> | [991][1008]        |
> | [1006][1007][1008] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebabc209cf0f080931bc208009770968)*

Answer (score 0):

This is a very odd structure in my opinion, but if you want to find every row that contains [1007] or [991] I would probably use the LIKE operator with the % wildcard.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `explanations` 
WHERE `id_Verse` like '%[991]%' or `id_Verse` like '%[1007]%'
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/